# Ubuntu 14.04 and VMWare: cannot install hgfs

Tags: 14.04, vmware-tools

I have patched official VMWare tools with https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches
These patches were required to compile VMWqare tools under Ubuntu 14.04 without compilation errors.
Than I listed shared folders and ran into error:

```
~$ lsmod | grep hgfs
vmhgfs                 53979  1 
vmw_vmci               62966  1 vmhgfs
~$ vmware-hgfsclient 
myshare
~$ ls -la /mnt/hgfs/
ls: cannot access /mnt/hgfs/: Not a directory
```

Also I tried to mount it to different directory with similar result:

```
~$ sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ ~/Shares
~$ ls -la ~/Shares/
ls: cannot access /home/ubuntu/Shares/: Not a directory
```

Could you help me with this trouble?

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue.  I was running VMplayer 6.0.1 which used VMware-Tools-9.6.1.  When I upgraded to VMplayer 6.0.2 with VMware-Tools-9.6.2 the HGFS mounts worked fine again.  Give that a shot.