# VMWare 10 Windows 8 (host) Ubuntu 14.04 (guest) shared folder won't mount

Tags: shared-folders, vmware-workstation

I am using vmware workstation 10 (win 8 host)
before,I used ubuntu 14.04 and for sharing folder from windows to ubuntu:I go to the settings of my windows VM, and select the Options Tab and there "shared folder"

and in ubuntu desktop,I found the folder that was shared in mnt directory.

but now ,I've installed ubuntu 14.10,but this way not working....

against this:[VMWare Windows 7 (host) Ubuntu 14.04 (guest) shared folder won't mount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459993/vmware-windows-7-host-ubuntu-14-04-guest-shared-folder-wont-mount)
I am using vmware 10

can u please tell me why?and how can I do that??

tnx

Comment: As I recall, the VMWare 10 tools do not fully compile in Ubuntu 14.04 - you might be able to find a solution in the VMWare community forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the VMware Tools are not modified yet for the 14.10+ kernel.  As such, the Shared Folders functionality fails to build.

Ultimately, we have to see if there are alternative options.  And there is.  First, remove the VMware Tools from the guest.  Then, install `open-vm-tools` which is an open source spin of the VMware Tools onto the guest.  That program exists in the repos so you can install it with `apt-get`

This should then help a little with the shared folders.